# python force a specific key to always be at the start of dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

How can I force a particular key to always be at the start of a dictionary.
E.g. if I have a list of dictionaries like this:

```
source = [{'age':39, 'name':'Homer','gender':'male', 'IQ':0}, {'age':10, 'gender':'male', 'IQ':0,'name':'Bart'}]
```

Need 'name' to always be the first key in the dict:

```
source = [{'name':'Homer','age':39, 'gender':'male', 'IQ':0}, {'name':'Bart','age':10, 'gender':'male','IQ':0}]
```

I have tried to use operator but that orders value of name in alphabetic order which is not what I want.

```
from operator import itemgetter
newlist = source.sort(key=operator.itemgetter('name'))
```

Comment: Dictionaries are unordered. Try using an OrderedDict

Comment: "It is best to think of a dictionary as an unordered set of key: value pairs" - [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

Comment: [`OrderedDict` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#ordereddict-objects)

Comment: I edited the answer, any luck?

Comment: What is the sorted_key? I do not know what will be my keys. The above is just an example.  What I know is 'name' will always be there and I want it to be first.

Comment: Why does it matter that name is first?

Comment: @ Mark  OK edited the answer..

Answer (score 6):

I would try [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) as below, I just used `counter` variable as key to the `defaultdict` that stores value as `ordereddict` and this ordereddict is an ordered dictionary as the name suggests, you can use this ordereddict as regular dictionary- see i use attribute access i.e. printing  value of `name` key by `item[1]['name']`. Finally `sort_order` is a dictionary that stores the order of keys as value you can modify this as you want.

```
from collections import OrderedDict,defaultdict
data = defaultdict(OrderedDict)
source = [{'age':39, 'name':'Homer','gender':'male', 'IQ':0}, {'age':10, 'gender':'male', 'IQ':0,'name':'Bart'}]
counter = 0
sort_order = {'IQ': 1, 'gender': 2, 'age': 3, 'name': 0}
for i in source:
    odrded_keys = sorted(i,key=lambda x: sort_order[x])
    tmp = OrderedDict(sorted(i.items(),key=lambda x: sort_order[x[0]]))
    data[counter].update(tmp)
    counter+=1
for item in  data.items():
    print item[1]
    print item[1]['name']
```

Output printed-

```
OrderedDict([('name', 'Homer'), ('IQ', 0), ('gender', 'male'), ('age', 39)])
Homer
OrderedDict([('name', 'Bart'), ('IQ', 0), ('gender', 'male'), ('age', 10)])
Bart
```

---

**EDIT**

As discussed in the comment (OP does not know the length of keys but there is a key in them that is `name` and it needs to be the first) i modified the code as below-

```
from collections import OrderedDict,defaultdict
data = defaultdict(OrderedDict)
source = [{'age':39, 'name':'Homer','gender':'male', 'IQ':0}, {'age':10, 'gender':'male', 'IQ':0,'name':'Bart'}]
counter = 0
for i in source:
    #get keys dynamically and remove 'name' form it and insert at first
    keys = i.keys()
    keys.remove('name')
    keys.insert(0,'name')
    #sort the dictionary by list element index- i.e. position
    tmp = OrderedDict(sorted(i.items(),key=lambda x: keys.index(x[0])))
    data[counter].update(tmp)
    counter+=1
for item in  data.items():
    print item[1]
    print item[1]['name']
```

Output-

```
OrderedDict([('name', 'Homer'), ('IQ', 0), ('gender', 'male'), ('age', 39)])
Homer
OrderedDict([('name', 'Bart'), ('IQ', 0), ('gender', 'male'), ('age', 10)])
Bart
```

Comment: My output needs to be in this format: `source = [{'name':'Homer','age':39, 'gender':'male', 'IQ':0}, {'name':'Bart','age':10, 'gender':'male','IQ':0}].`

Comment: @ Mark Then your keys are `name age gender IQ` and you want in this sequence? If yes then just edit first script as  `sort_order = {'IQ': 3, 'gender': 2, 'age': 1, 'name': 0}`